# Sendkeys Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F6 (Deep Freeze)

Tags: c#, combinations, sendkeys

I tried to send key combination of Shift+Ctrl+Alt+F6 to bring up Deep Freeze workstation configuration screen
SendKeys.Send("+^%{F6}");
And SendKeys.Send("+^%({F6})");

But neither one worked
Deep Freeze doesn't have any window to show until after that sent

In AutoIT version, I can use Send("+^!{F6}") and that worked

Could someone point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure it doesnt respond to a keys down or keys up rather than keypress ..

Comment: Maybe you have to activate the window first to make the key combination work?!?

Comment: @BugFinder: not sure what you mean, but to launch DF dialog box, I have to hold Shift+Ctrl+Alt while pressing then release F6. RandRandom: Deep Freeze has no window until after that combination sent to bring it up

Comment: @user2490287  then you need to understand more about windows messages, there are various messages, key down, key up, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to help.
Found out Sendkeys.Send will only work if it has target, if not then it just send to it self app. Deep Freeze setting console has no GUI until after the combination keys show it, that's why I cannot use it.
AutoIT's Send function doesn't need target, it just act like physical keyboard work.
I temporarily used NuGet InputSimulator to get the job done. Hate to have the dll in executable folder for it to work though, so will look into convert to native PostMessage or SendInput once I learn more about those to understand.
Right now my code is simply as:

```
s.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(
            new[] { VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.MENU, 
VirtualKeyCode.SHIFT },
            new[] { VirtualKeyCode.F6 }
            );
```